# Unable to fetch the data from firestore even after changing the Database rules to allow all reads and writes

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**What I am doing**

So, I connected two of my applications to the same database one is using real-time database and I successfully migrated some of the data from real-time database to cloud firestore using cloud functions and the other application is using cloud firestore.

The firebase auth is working fine for both the applications, first application is successfully fetching the data from real-time database

**What my problem is**

but the problem is the second app is unable to fetch the data from cloud firestore, so I successfully catch the exception and it says "com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions."

**What I did to resolve**

so from the exception I am able to figure out that it's a permission issue, so I changed my rules for the cloud firestore

**Earlier firestore rule**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Changed firebase rules**

so I tried both of the below rule one by one to resolve the issue

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

but unfortunately none of the above is able to solve the issue
I am still getting the same exception even after publishing the new rules

**UPDATE**

screenshot of the current firestore rules

[image]

**Kotlin code**

```
class Toppers {
    private val firestore:FirebaseFirestore by lazy{
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    }

    private val toppersList = mutableListOf<Topper>()
    private val toppers = MutableLiveData<List<Topper>>()

    init {
        toppers.value = toppersList
    }

    fun getToppers():LiveData<List<Topper>>
    {
        firestore.collection("Toppers").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->

            if(task.isSuccessful)
            {
                toppersList.clear()
                for(topper in task.result!!)
                {
                    Log.d("(Saquib)","data is fetched "+topper.get("name").toString())
                    toppersList.add(
                        Topper(topper.get("name").toString(),
                               topper.get("percentage").toString(),
                               topper.get("imgurl").toString(),
                               topper.get("resulturl").toString(),
                               topper.get("rollno").toString(),
                               topper.get("schoolname").toString(),
                               topper.get("session").toString(),
                               topper.get("stream").toString(),
                               topper.get("standard").toString())
                    )
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("(Saquib)","unable to fetch the data "+task.exception?.cause.toString())
            }
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            toppers.value = toppersList
        }
        return toppers
    }
}
```

**Android Logs**

*(Saquib): unable to fetch the data io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.*

can anyone please help me out, 
i'll be really thankful to you

Comment: i very much doubt if its firebase security rule issues, since the default rule says you have read and write access on any documents, which simply means you are kind of admin.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your response i have added the screenshot of the current firestore rules in my question as per your instruction, but unfortunately i am still getting the same exception

Comment: Where is your logcat error? Are you sure you are getting problem in Read Write? You are may be trying to get wrong data.

Comment: Hi Pratik, Thanks to come forward, i have added the android logs along with the kotlin code please find them under the updates

Answer (score 0):

Go in Database -> Rules ->

```
 allow read, write: if false; to true;
```

But be warned, this means there is no security at all to your firestore database